# How can I link a button to another page using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering how I can make my button link to another page. Below is my attempt. However, the button doesn't link to the "About Me" page. The files are all in the same folder and I haven't spelt the same wrong therefore, have I coded the button wrong that's why it doesn't linked to the desired page?

```
<div class="container text-center">
            <a href="About Me.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Click here to find more about me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The button link should work fine

Answer (score 1):

You should put into the href the file name of the page "About Me".

A tip: try to avoid spaces, which should be encoded inside the URL string.

```
<div class="container text-center">
   <a href="about-me.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Click here to find more about me</a>
</div>
```